# After timeout keep trying request

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've just started using Python to scrape the data. But my code as below freezes during work and I guess that's because some url did not response anything; I guess it would work if I just try that url again. My question here is, if I just revise the code like,
reshomee = requests.get(homeUrl, headers=headerss, timeout=10)
then does this code try that url again after 10 seconds with no response? I am just worried if it would be just over without trying again...?
I couldn't help asking this because I have no idea how to try this code since url freezes very rare and randomly. Thank you!

```
def reshome(tries=0):
    try:
         reshomee = requests.get(homeUrl, headers=headerss)
         return reshomee
    except Exception as e:
         print(e)
         if tries < 10:
            print('try:' + str(tries))
            sleep(tries*30+100)
            return reshome(tries+1)
         else:
            print('cannot make it')
```

Comment: If you set a timeout, it will throw an exception if it took too long (see: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts). If you want to retry the URL you will have to do so manually.

Comment: If it goes to an exception then I am just happy. I actually define url outside of this function therefore, it would just try the same url over again. Thank you!!!

Comment: If you check for an exception make sure you check specifically for the timeout exception `requests.exceptions.Timeout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use requests.exceptions in the module.

```
def reshome(tries=0):
try:
     reshomee = requests.get(homeUrl, headers=headerss, timeout=0.001)
     return reshomee
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        return reshome(tries+1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One quick question: then what if it faces 500ish server errors? Where would it goes to? Should I specify another exception? Thanks!